# what does the following message api id mean

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Can anyone tell me what these represent?

```
&H100 
&H109
&H200 
&H20E
```

Does anyone know where I can find more info on these and what they mean?

Comment: I was hoping someone can point me to the right direction. I belive &H100 = KeyDown?

Comment: These are just numbers, there is no way to know what these numbers represent without additional information.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17758555/how-to-determine-inactivity-on-a-winform it may help...

Comment: [Type Characters - Visual Basic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9cz43ek.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are numeric values represented as hexadecimal literals.  The `&H` prefix is the VB.NET syntax for a hexadecimal number.  Numbers are numbers.  They always mean the same thing.  It's just a different way of representing the values, just as different languages use different words to represent the same ideas.  Normally, numbers are represented as base-10, but sometimes hexadecimal can be more convenient because every two digits is exactly one byte.  Each digit ranges from 0-F, so a two digit number can range from 00 (0) through FF (255) which is the range of one byte.  Most languages represent hexadecimal with a `0x` prefix.  VB is unusual for having `&H` as the prefix.  Here are the base-10 equivalents:

- `&H100` = 256
- `&H109` = 265
- `&H200` = 512
- `&H20E` = 526

The meanings of these values depends on the API that uses them.  If these are window message codes, [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644927(v=VS.85).aspx#system_defined) would be a good place to start.