# How come Environment.TickCount and keyboard's lastinputinfo.dwTime is same?

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi

I am making to get idle time of using mouse and keyboard. I get mouse idle time so far, but I couldn't get keyboard's idle time.

when I check 'Environment.TickCount' and 'lastInputInfo.dwTime', they are always same, so idle time is always 0 in keyboard.

This is method of getting last input time:

```
 public DateTime GetLastInputTime()
    {
        var lastInputInfo = new LASTINPUTINFO();
        lastInputInfo.dwTime = 0;
        lastInputInfo.cbSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(lastInputInfo);

        GetLastInputInfo(ref lastInputInfo);

        return DateTime.Now.AddMilliseconds(-(Environment.TickCount - lastInputInfo.dwTime));
    }
```

This is method of geting idle time:

```
public static uint GetIdleTime()
    {
        var lastinput = new LASTINPUTINFO();
        lastinput.cbSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(lastinput);

        GetLastInputInfo(ref lastinput);
        return ((uint)Environment.TickCount - lastinput.dwTime);
    }
```

and this is keyboard event:

```
private void keyboard_KeyBoardKeyPressed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (GetIdleTime() > 10000)
        {
            timer1.Enabled = false;
            MessageBox.Show("keyboard mvoe test");
            timer1.Enabled = true;
        }
        label_keyboard.Text = FormatDateTime(lastInput.GetLastInputTime());
    }
```

I set 10 sec to check if I didn't press keyboard in 10 sec, the message would be pop up.

Comment: You appear to call `GetLastInputInfo` in response to an input event ........

Comment: I don't get it.. I can get idle time of mouse just like that. If I want to pop up messagebox in keyboard situation, but should I do?

Comment: The system doesn't track idle time for individual input devices. You press a key, the input idle time resets to 0.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17761283/17034