# Show Form when mouse stop moving

Tags: c#, winforms

How can I display a form when the mouse stops moving after a timer interval?

When you move the mouse, the countdown stops

```cs
private async void frmMain_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await StartAsync(5000);
}

private async Task StartAsync(int interval)
{
    await Task.Delay(interval);
    using (var f3 = new frm_LockScreen())
    {
        f3.my_EmpID = my_Emp_ID;
        f3.ShowDialog();          
    }
    this.Show();
}
```

Comment: Use Win32's built-in user-inactivity-timer (which is what triggers the Screen Saver and power/idle events, it's exposed via `GetLastInputInfo`)`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getlastinputinfo?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: @Dai I'm just being silly here, but what if the user only interacts via keyboard or other interface and still doesn't touch the mouse? the user-inactivity-timer wouldn't do the job then. My point being "not moving the mouse" doesn't necessarily imply "being inactive".

Comment: @jarmanso7 That's not what the OP asked for, though. They specifically said "mouse".

Comment: @Dai Stop gaslighting. You stole my argument.

Comment: Actually the `GetLastInputInfo()` API also checks keyboard events as well as mouse events.

Comment: @MatthewWatson exactly. That's my point.

Comment: @jarmanso7 That's not what "gaslighting" means...

Comment: I bet the OP does also mean to include using the keyboard, but just didn't think to mention it. OP will need to confirm.

Comment: @Dai yes, gaslighting is making a point (like you did in your first comment), and when someone raises a concern about it, you change your thesis. Let me paraphrase, you first said "You can use GetLastInputInfo to check for the user's inactivity". Then I replied "What if OP is not interested in inactivity, but only in mouse not moving", and then you gaslight "But he said specifically "mouse"." Which was my point in the first place.

Comment: @MatthewWatson I think so, hence I started with "I'm just being silly". But probably for OP's needs, GetLastInputInfo would do the job

Comment: what about clicking (without moving the mouse), or scrolling the mousewheel? should that reset the countdown as well?

Comment: @jarmanso7 No, "gaslighting" is when you use municipal gas supply as a fuel for illumination.

Comment: @Dai your gaslighting skills are superb.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17761283/17034

Answer (score 1):

Following @Dai 's suggestion, this is another way to implement a solution using again a Timer, but calling Win32's `GetLastInputInfo` instead of using a mouse hook.

First, place a timer in your main form with an interval short enough that works for you, for example `Interval = 1000` and set it to `Enabled = True`:

[image: TimerProperties]

Then, reference Win32's `GetLastInputInfo` like this:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool GetLastInputInfo(ref LASTINPUTINFO plii);
```

After that, create a static method to `GetLastInputTimeInSeconds` calculate in seconds how much time has passed since the last user activity leveraging `GetLastInputInfo`:

```
static int GetLastInputTimeInSeconds()
{
    int idleTime = 0;
    LASTINPUTINFO lastInputInfo = new LASTINPUTINFO();
    lastInputInfo.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(lastInputInfo);
    lastInputInfo.dwTime = 0;

    int envTicks = Environment.TickCount;

    if (GetLastInputInfo(ref lastInputInfo))
    {
        int lastInputTick = Convert.ToInt32(lastInputInfo.dwTime);

        idleTime = envTicks - lastInputTick;
    }

    return (idleTime > 0) ? (idleTime / 1000) : idleTime;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct LASTINPUTINFO
{
    public static readonly int SizeOf = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(LASTINPUTINFO));

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
    public int cbSize;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
    public UInt32 dwTime;
}
```

Inside your timer's tick event handler `timer1_Tick`, simply call `GetLastInputTimeInSeconds` to verify if more than a certain amount of time has passed. If that's the case, then show a new form:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (GetLastInputTimeInSeconds() > 10)
    {
        var form2 = new Form2();

        form2.Show();
    }
}
```

Just in case, here you are the full code of your main Form, without the designer generated code:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace stackoverflow_77557770
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (GetLastInputTimeInSeconds() > 10)
            {
                var form2 = new Form2();

                form2.Show();
            }
        }

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern bool GetLastInputInfo(ref LASTINPUTINFO plii);

        static int GetLastInputTimeInSeconds()
        {
            int idleTime = 0;
            LASTINPUTINFO lastInputInfo = new LASTINPUTINFO();
            lastInputInfo.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(lastInputInfo);
            lastInputInfo.dwTime = 0;

            int envTicks = Environment.TickCount;

            if (GetLastInputInfo(ref lastInputInfo))
            {
                int lastInputTick = Convert.ToInt32(lastInputInfo.dwTime);

                idleTime = envTicks - lastInputTick;
            }

            return (idleTime > 0) ? (idleTime / 1000) : idleTime;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        struct LASTINPUTINFO
        {
            public static readonly int SizeOf = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(LASTINPUTINFO));

            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
            public int cbSize;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
            public UInt32 dwTime;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of a timer and a mouse hook to achieve this. The idea is simple: use the timer to countdown from a specific time to 0, and when the countdown arrives to 0 show a new Form. Then, with the mouse hook track if there's a mouse movement, and if there is, then reset the counter back to the initial time, so the countdown gets restarted and the form is not shown as a result of moving the mouse.

Place a timer in your main form with an interval short enough that works for you, for example `Interval = 1000` and set it to `Enabled = True`:

[image: TimerProperties]

Then, in your form's class create a field `secondsLeft` to track the amount of time remaining (I set it to 10 seconds).

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    int secondsLeft = 10;

    [...]
}
```

In the `timer1_Tick` eventhandler, decrease the timer by 1 each second. Also add a check for when `secondsLeft`, the countdown, reaches 0. If it reaches 0, then show the new form:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    secondsLeft--;

    if (secondsLeft <= 0)
    {
        var newForm = new Form2();
        newForm.Show();
    }
}
```

Finally, add a class `GlobalMouseHandler` inheriting from `IMessageFilter` as explained in ([this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063974/how-do-i-capture-the-mouse-move-event)). Inside `gmh_TheMouseMoved()`, reset the field `secondsLeft` back to the full time of 10 seconds:

```
private void gmh_TheMouseMoved()
{
    secondsLeft = 10;
}

public class GlobalMouseHandler : IMessageFilter
{
    private const int WM_MOUSEMOVE = 0x0200;

    public event MouseMovedEvent TheMouseMoved;

    public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == WM_MOUSEMOVE)
        {
            if (TheMouseMoved != null)
            {
                TheMouseMoved();
            }
        }
        // Always allow message to continue to the next filter control
        return false;
    }
}
```

Just in case, this is the full code for your main form, excluding the part in Form1.Designer.cs:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    int secondsLeft = 10;

    public Form1()
    {
        GlobalMouseHandler gmh = new GlobalMouseHandler();
        gmh.TheMouseMoved += new MouseMovedEvent(gmh_TheMouseMoved);
        Application.AddMessageFilter(gmh);

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void gmh_TheMouseMoved()
    {
        secondsLeft = 10;
    }

    public delegate void MouseMovedEvent();

    public class GlobalMouseHandler : IMessageFilter
    {
        private const int WM_MOUSEMOVE = 0x0200;

        public event MouseMovedEvent TheMouseMoved;

        public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message m)
        {
            if (m.Msg == WM_MOUSEMOVE)
            {
                if (TheMouseMoved != null)
                {
                    TheMouseMoved();
                }
            }
            // Always allow message to continue to the next filter control
            return false;
        }
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        secondsLeft--;

        if (secondsLeft <= 0)
        {
            var newForm = new Form2();
            newForm.Show();
        }
    }
}
```